# ERROR >> undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-replication, tungsten-replicator

[SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhRNR.png)I'm trying to perform Tungsten Replicator installation using tpm by typing:

```
./tools/tpm install alpha \
--install-directory=/opt/continuent \
--master=tungsten1 \
--members=tungsten1,tungsten2 \
--enable-heterogeneous-master=true \
--enable-batch-service=true \
--replication-password=tungsten \
--replication-user=tungstenmysql \
--skip-validation-check=HostsFileCheck \
--skip-validation-check=ReplicationServicePipelines \
--start-and-report=true
```

However, I keep getting, "ERROR >> undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass". Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Without a stack trace this is pretty much a mystery. Take it up with the TPM team?

Comment: @tadman I just added screenshot of the output. Can you identify the problem by looking at that?

Comment: Still no idea what might be the issue here.